# How does appannie.com get app rankings to 1500?

Tags: app-store

I've been using Apple's search API and RSS feeds to look at top-grossing apps.  As far as I can tell, Apple limits the results to 300 when looking at the top-grossing apps, but somehow appannie.com has apps listed in top grossing to 1500.

Anyone know how they get their numbers?

Comment: If you snoop the http requests that older versions of iTunes on a Mac or PC use to request information from the App Store to display, you will find some list requests include a page number.  If you increase the page number you might see apps farther down the list.  But these undocumented protocols are most likely subject to change at any time.

Comment: Good idea but I don't have any old versions of itunes.  I would think someone would have documented it somewhere but I can't find anything.

Comment: did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Nope, I still don't know how they do it.  Haven't been able to find anything about the undocumented page number feature...

Comment: I find it an amazingly interesting question --- so many people are relying on the stats of App Annie and still it is not clear how the data is mined, aggregated etc.

Answer (score 4):

Oliver Lo, the VP of Marketing at App Annie, gave a few hints during an interview with pocketgamer.biz (quoted below).

> The firm offers a sales analytics tool for developers that both
>   gathers their sales numbers and processes them. Indeed, App Annie's
>   analytics tool is used by over 150,000 apps and, in particular, over
>   40 percent of the top 100 publishers by revenue.
>
> Once a developer connects their App Annie account with their iTunes
>   Connect account, the sales data is automatically downloaded and
>   processed.
>
> While App Annie keeps the data from that tool completely anonymous, it
>   does combine all the download and revenue data it has access to
>   together to build a global model of sales.
>
> That data is then correlated with the public ranking data in the top
>   app lists to place sales figures with ranks.
>
> **Filling in the blanks**
>
> "Imagine a Y axis that represents downloads and X axis that represents
>   rankings," adds Lo.
>
> "Essentially we create a model of those two data points, correlating
>   them and growing a distribution of those points through advanced
>   statistics.
>
> "Through that statistical correlation we are able to generate market
>   estimates for the downloads and the revenue of the entire App Store
>   ecosystem."

Source: http://www.pocketgamer.biz/feature/47064/stateside-getting-to-grips-with-app-annies-app-store-stats/